# Adding text to footer in Django admin page

Tags: html, css, django

I'm trying to customize the auto generated django admin page to something more personal. I would like to add text in the footer but so far everything I've tried has not worked. Here's the html. This attempt right here will show the footer text right after the content without the footer bar created by the css. Here's the html:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Sunstreet Administration' %}{% endblock %}

{% block extrastyle %}

<!-- <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="headerfooter.css" type="text/css"/>
</head> -->

<style>


#header{ width:100%;
background-color: 
#DF4F44;
border-bottom: solid 3px #999;
display: block;
background-image:url("/img/sunstreet.png") no-repeat right top; }



#branding h1{ color: #fff; }
.module h2, .module caption, .inline-group h2 { background:#ccc url(/img/admin/nav-bg.gif) bottom          left repeat-x; color: #333940; }
a.section:link, a.section:visited { color: #9CA974; }


#footer h5{ position:fixed; bottom:0;
width: 100%; height:5px; background-color: #DF4F44; 
border-bottom: solid 3px #999;
}


</style>

<!-- <footer class="footer">

    <div class="copyright">
        Copyright &copy; 2014 LOL. All rights reserved
    </div>
</footer> -->

{% endblock %}
{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'Database' %}</h1>

{% endblock %}



{% block nav-global %}

{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
<h5> 'Text in footer'  </h5>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Where have you put this template?

Answer (score 0):

You try:
From

```
<!-- <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="headerfooter.css" type="text/css"/>
</head> -->
```

to:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!-- <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= " {% static "headerfooter.css" %}" />
</head> -->
```

Put headerfooter.css in folder static/headerfooter.css